# How to run Pyrogram Client if type of Telegram api_id is "str"?

Tags: pyrogram

I faced an issue in Pyrogram: if Telegram api_id type is str an error occurs:

```
".../pyrogram/client.py", line 233, in init
    self.api_id = int(api_id) if api_id else None
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123xxx'
```

Although the Pyrogram v2.0.106 [documentation](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/client#pyrogram.Client) states that Client api_id can be int|str.

Perhaps there is already some solution to this problem?